# Creating a table in NexusDB with german umlauts?

Tags: sql, nexusdb

I'm trying to import a `CREATE TABLE` statement in NexusDB.
The table name contains some german umlauts and so do some field names but I receive an error that there were some invalid characters in my statement (obviously the umlauts...).

My question is now: can somebody give a solution or any ideas to solve my problem?

It's not so easy to just change the umlauts into equivalent terms like `ä` -> `ae` or `ö` -> `oe` since our application has fixed table names every customer uses currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use characters outside what is normally permitted in the SQL standard. This will bite you not only in NexusDB, but in many other databases as well. Take special note that there is a good chance you will also run into problems when you want to access data via ODBC etc, as other environments may also have similar standard restrictions. My *strong* recommendation would be to avoid use of characters outside the SQL naming standard for tables, no matter which database is used.

However... having said all that, given that NexusDB is one of the most flexible database systems for the programmer (it comes with full source), there is already a solution. If you add an "extendedliterals" define to your database server project, then a larger array of characters are considered valid. For the exact change this enables, see the nxcValidIdentChars constant in the nxllConst.pas unit. The constant may also be changed if required.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! this is what i already told our customer, but as i said before: the tables are already present in various customer dbs with the same name "solution". We try mapping the table names in the code now.